# Prepared statement PDO gives NULL result n DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've developed a form in php which would allow the user to submit a simple job application.
Before sending the user input to my database I santize and validate my data.

```
<?php
$geslachtErr = $voornaamErr = $familienaamErr = $emailErr = $telErr = $afileErr = "";
$geslacht = $voornaam = $familienaam = $email = $tel = $afile = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  if (empty($_POST["geslacht"])) {
    $geslachtErr = "geslacht is required";
  } else {
    $geslacht = test_input($_POST["geslacht"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["voornaam"])) {
    $voornaamErr = "voornaam is required";
  } else {
    $voornaam = test_input($_POST["voornaam"]);
    // check if voornaam only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$voornaam)) {
      $voornaamErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }
```

The function that I use to sanitize the user input looks like this:

```
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

My html look like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> >


      <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <p><span class="error">* verplichte velden.</span></p>
              <label>Geslacht</label><span class="error">* <?php echo $geslachtErr;?></span>
                <select name="geslacht" value="<?= isset($_POST['geslacht']) ? $_POST['geslacht'] : ''; ?>">>
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="man">man</option>
                  <option value="vrouw">vrouw</option>
                </select>
        </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->        

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>Voornaam</label><span class="error">* <?php echo $voornaamErr;?></span>
            <input type="text" name="voornaam" value="<?= isset($_POST['voornaam']) ? $_POST['voornaam'] : ''; ?>">
          </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->
```

If I than do a test and `echo` all my fields in the same form I get all the results.

But I want this data to be sent to a mysql db.
So I use PDO with Prepared Statement. This file is called dbcon.php

```
<?php
$servername = "xxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=xxxxx", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sollicitatie_form (geslacht, voornaam, familienaam, email, tel) 
    VALUES (:geslacht, :voornaam, :familienaam, :email, :tel)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':geslacht', $geslacht);
    $stmt->bindParam(':voornaam', $voornaam);
    $stmt->bindParam(':familienaam', $familienaam);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tel', $tel);

    $stmt->execute();


    echo "New records created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn->null;
```

Now this is for sure where I'm going wrong, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

When I want to sent the user input to my mysql db I change the action in my html from

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> >
```

to

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="dbcon.php >
```

When I than submit data I get all "NULL" in my database...

The connection with my mysql db is working. I've double tested it.
I'm pretty sure that the sanatizing and validation is correct as when I test it locally (without sending it to mysql db) I get all the correct info.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: why are you using `function test_input()` AND a prepared statement? You don't need that.

Comment: Any reason why you're posting to dbcon.php and not using `$_POST['geslacht']`, `$_POST['voornaam']`, etc.?

Comment: @Fred-ii- So I don't need to sanitize my data when I use a prepared statement? But how will I be sure that my data is clean than? Sorry for the may obvious question but I'm a student developer.

Comment: a prepared statement does all that.

Comment: @cteski, and where do I need to change this?

Comment: you should give the type on bindParam:
if it's a string $stmt->bindParam(':geslacht', $geslacht, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: @Fred-ii-, ok, I wasn't aware, thank you. I will adjust this in my script. I will only keep the validation and required. Just to be sure. I remove my function and instead of `else {
    $geslacht = test_input($_POST["geslacht"]);
  }` I use else   `{
    $geslacht = $_POST["geslacht"];
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what am I doing wrong?

don't store things pre-encoded in the db. and for that matter, don't sanitize input, validate & encode it. and don't call it `test_input` if you really mean `sanitize_input` - instead, call it `sanitize_input`. and **don't ever use stripslashes**, its not a good fit for anything. if you need to html encode something, use htmlspecialchars (or htmlentities), if you need to encode it for SQL, use PDO::quote, if you need to encode it for shell arguments, use escapeshellarg. if you need to encode it for regex, use preg_quote, *never stripslashes, the only thing it is good for, is corrupting your data.*

the proper way to html encode arbitrary strings:

```
function hhb_tohtml(string $str): string {
    return htmlentities ( $str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true );
}
```

(optionally replace htmlentities with htmlspecialchars, but its the same input arguments)

and never do this:

```
action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>
```

if you want the POST to go to the current page, simply omit the action property completely. and most of the time, its best to let the browser decide encoding type itself (browsers will usually choose `enctype="multipart/form-data"` when files are bing updated, and application/x-www-urlencoded when no files are being uploaded, which is usually the smart thing to do, as multipart has a large metadata overhead, but 0 actual file content overhead, while urlencoded has a minimal metadata overhead, but a massive overhead for encoding binary data (up to 300% the original binary size), which files are usually made off of. let the browser choose itself, unless you have a very good reason not to.)

as for why you're getting NULLs, well look here

```
$stmt->bindParam(':geslacht', $geslacht);
```

you never define $geslacht, what you need is

```
$stmt->bindParam(':geslacht', $_POST['geslacht']);
```

maybe i missed something, but i'm out of time

Comment: thank you very much. I thought I called $geslacht. It works now. Also thanks to all other replies. All comments where very very useful for future reference! Thank you!

Comment: I was a little bit to quick. I've changed `$stmt->bindParam(':geslacht', $geslacht);` to `$stmt->bindParam(':geslacht', $_POST['geslacht']);` but now my data validation is gone.....

Comment: when committing it to the db, use PDO::quote or prepared statements (you've done the latter, good job), and when you print it out to the user again, use the tohtml() function i showed you above - it guarantees that its valid UTF8 html, without letting any script injection or tags get inserted. what do you want to validate, exactly? your preg validation above won't allow people to play chess in your homemade forum. ♚ ♛ ♜ ♝ ♞ ♟ ♔ ♕ ♖ ♗ ♘ ♙, nor write their résumé , nor talk about programming ([]^$_ etc)

Comment: you might want to validate that what they're posting is valid UTF-8 though. `mb_check_encoding($str,'UTF-8')` - EDIT: fixed a typo, originally wrote mb_detect_encoding, which is wrong

Comment: thank you for your very clear explination. One more question. Where do I put the tohtml function?

Comment: i usually have a file dedicated to these types of commonly useful misc functions, and in every file i want those functions, i use `require_once('useful_functions.inc.php');`

Comment: And I want to validate if the "voornaam" is a name and there are now numbers in it, same for "familiename". I want to validate that the email addres is an emailaddress and that the phonenumber is a phonenumber

Comment: for validating emails, theres `filter_validate($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`, for validating names, i would use `if(!preg_match( '/^[[:alnum:][:space:]]+$/u', $name )` , as for reliably validating phone numbers across the globe, that's actually a complex task, check https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/master/docs/Phone.md - though a simple regex could account for most schemes - don't go validating names by [a-zA-Z] though, Kurt Gödel and René Descartes would fail the test! ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes )  - the [alnum] and /u will support unicode a-z, which accept

Comment: @Newbie18 which rightfully accept both Kurt Gödel and René Descartes, and countless other chinese, vietnamese, norwegian, japanese, etc, names, while still not allowing the name <>!~

Comment: And file extensions? I only want to accept pdf, doc and docx. If anything else the user should get a message that I only accepte the above extensions.

Comment: @Newbie18 `$whitelist=['pdf','doc','docx']; if(!in_array(pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION),$whitelist,true)){die("invalid file type! must be 1 of: ".implode(' - ',$whitelist));}`